# DirectionsService, Request Denied, calculated LatLng

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm not able to add DirectionsService into an existing map. origin and destination points are calculated (sic!) by code. Maybe, this is the problem? Here we have the code, very simplified, of course:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var directionsService;
var directionsDisplay;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat:47, lng:8.3}
    });

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var von  = new google.maps.LatLng(47, 8.3);
    var nach = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 8.43);

    calculateAndDisplayRoute(von, nach);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(von, nach) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: von,
        destination: nach,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

What could be the reason for getting REQUEST_DENIED?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error (the [posted code (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tt0xzvco/)) works for me.

Comment: Did you enable Directions API web service in your project? Maps JavaScript API counts usage against corresponding web service quota.

Answer (score 0):

THX, Directions AP wasn't enabled. It wasn't enough to use Javascript API only